# Windows 7: how to setup a Homegroup - IPv6 error?

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, ipv6, homegroup

Every time I try to setup a Homegroup I get an error message that I need to have IPv6 enabled.  When I check the system it says that IPv6 is enabled.

Comment: Is this the first time you have joined or set up a Homegroup on this box or on this network?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. I don't know anything about it (which is why I gave a link) but after Googling it...

[here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7network/thread/4865cd00-4ed9-4407-83eb-4babd99bf1e3)

Comment: Wow, my answers last year were so terrible.